Unwanted Top and Bottom Spacing in .NET MAUI iOS Simulator
Problem
When running my .NET MAUI application on an iOS simulator (connected through Mac pairing), the app displays with unexpected blank spaces at the top and bottom of the screen. This issue occurs specifically on the iOS simulator despite successful connection and running of the simulator.
Environment

.NET MAUI (targeting net8.0)

macOS with Windows pairing

iOS Simulator

Visual Studio


Relevant Code
Project File (Relevant Parts)
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst;net8.0-android34.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

SplashScreen XAML (Relevant Parts)
xaml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TIAERP_App.Features.Auth.Views.Registration.RegistrationView"
               xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
              ios:Page.UseSafeArea="False"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TIAERP_App.Utils.ResponsiveHelper" 
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             Title="RegistrationView" >

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" Padding="0">
        <!-- Header Bar -->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Padding="{helpers:ScreenThickness All=1.6}" Grid.Row="0">

            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource OnPrimaryColor} "
                            HeightRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =4}"
                            WidthRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Width = 8}"
                            BorderColor="{StaticResource OnPrimaryColor}"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Padding="{helpers:ScreenThickness All=0.22}"  >
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="OpenPartyCodePopup"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image Source="person.png" WidthRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Width =6.6}" HeightRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =3.4}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Frame>
            <Label Text="TiaERP@App" FontSize="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =3.6}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Image Source="red.gif" WidthRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Width = 4}" HeightRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Height=4}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- Content Section -->
        <StackLayout Padding="{helpers:ScreenThickness All=6}" Spacing="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =2}" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" >
            <!-- Tia.png Image -->
            <Grid
                     HeightRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =26}"
                     WidthRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Width =90}"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                <Grid.Shadow>
                    <Shadow
                     Brush="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                     Radius="20"
                     Offset="6,8" />
                </Grid.Shadow>
                <Image
                     Source="tia.png"
                     Aspect="Fill" />
            </Grid>

            <!-- Text Box with some text -->
            <Label Text="A Software for business that does everything. From Controlling your business to improving your profits and more." 
                   FontSize="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =2.5}" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label FontSize="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =2.5}" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="Visit: " FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" TextColor="Black"/>
                        <Span Text="www.goyalonline.com" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <!-- Footer Bar -->
        <Frame Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" HeightRequest="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =5}" Padding="{helpers:ScreenThickness All=0}" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Copyright © - All Rights Reserved www.goyalonline.com" 
           FontSize="{helpers:ScreenSize Height =1.78}" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>

using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using TIAERP_App.Features.Auth.Services;
using TIAERP_App.Utils.DeviceInfohelper;

namespace TIAERP_App.Features.Auth.Views.Registration
{
    public partial class RegistrationView : ContentPage
    {
        private RegistrationService _registrationService;
        private DeviceInfoHelper _deviceInfoHelper;

        public RegistrationView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _registrationService = new RegistrationService();
            _deviceInfoHelper = new DeviceInfoHelper();

        }
        private async void OpenPartyCodePopup(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var popup = new PartyCodePopup(Navigation);
            var info = await _deviceInfoHelper.GetDeviceInfo("3");
            Preferences.Set("NodeId", info);
            this.ShowPopup(popup);
        }
    }
}

What I've Tried

Set Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" and NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"

Added UIRequiresFullScreen in Info.plist

Confirmed proper simulator connection and running state


Expected Behavior
The app should fill the entire screen without any unwanted spacing at the top or bottom.
Actual Behavior
The app displays with unnecessary blank spaces at the top and bottom of the screen in the iOS simulator.
Screenshots
Tap here to see the image
Can anyone help identify what's causing these unwanted spaces and how to remove them?

Have you tried setting Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" in  the RegistrationView (not AppShell.xaml)?
